# Non-Renewing Subscription Restoration

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, icloud, non-renewing-subscription

**Background:**

Apple requires you to  implement a restoration mechanism to this type of purchases to let users to get back their purchases after wiping the device or to view purchases from user's other device.

One accepted approach form apple for doing this is to do an optional user registration and handle it on your server to save the transaction receipts. since apple don't do that like other type of purchases as non-consumable. which allow you to get all the receipts of the users to restore them.

Apple say that the registration should be optional. but we must indicate to the user that registration is required to view purchases from other devices.

**My Suggested Approach:**

I am going to implement the restoration mechanism by saving the purchases receipts in iCloud. I will indicate that logging into iCloud is required to access the subscription content from user's other iOS devices.

On purchasing succeeded app. will check if iCloud is available to save the subscription details(Transaction Receipt) Otherwise, subscriptions will be saved to User Defaults. Every time the app. is launched it will check if iCloud available and iCloud will be synced with User Defaults. subscriptions details available on User Defaults and not on the iCloud will be copied to the iCloud and the subscriptions that are available on iCloud and not on User Defaults will be copied to User Defaults.

Thats provide users the flexibility to login to iCloud in a future time just to move their subscriptions to another devices or just before they decided to delete the app. to save their subscription. (That all will exactly perform as we had the user registration option). Is that accepted?

Another thing. My app. suppose to work on iOS 4.x too. which mean that iCloud is not available. Is that ok too? or I have to give up running app. on iOS 4.x if I want to use iCloud approach? what if I also indicated that restoration will not be available for iOS 4.x?

Comment: I'm not sure how Apple would respond if you tell the user that restore is not possible on iOS 4.x devices. Since it seems entirely acceptable to tell a user your app is not going to work on earlier iOS versions, it would seem logically OK to allow a reduced function app to be available on earlier iOS versions. I'm not sure how Apple would view this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is that , the restoration of payment and other data should be handle by your application or by your side on the server. But i think it will increase your burden of coding. But registration is optional and if user wants that he will be able to use application on his other iOS devices also then u can make registration compulsory, otherwise the restoration of payment or data should be done using keychain.

If u have still doubt then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

So, in this case what if a user makes a purchase without signing into his iCloud account? We won't be providing him the content access on his other device in that case, right?

Is there any way to handle that scenario? Are we allowed to store the user's id and password into the iCloud? This may help us, but won't be a good idea to store the credentials.